# How to call a js function in a wordpress function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, plugins

I am trying to call a JS function in a Wordpress function in a plugin file. The JS file is successfully enqueued and reading the page source I can see the function is there waiting to be called. However I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsFunction is not defined
```

The plugin function executes on a gravity form submission and this has worked before but not for calling the JS function. This is the WP function:

```
function call_js_function() {
?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      jsFunction();
  </script>

<?php
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_7', 'call_js_function' );
```

jsFunction:

```
function jsFunction() {
  console.log('hello world');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try many options,

1. try to call jsFunction() in console and check if it has global
   access
2. make sure its defined globally
3. Is this function calling in header but the js  function defined in body ? if so it will cause an error. So make sure the js loads first before using the function in page.

Comment: I have tried to create a global function using 'window.jsFunction();' but this doesn't work. I get a different error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function): (anonymous function)' How can I define it globally?

Should Global functions be avoided?